# Distance function (without absolute value nor square root)

Tags: metric-spaces

I'm trying to invent or find a distance function in a two-dimensional space that only makes use of the basic arithmetic operations (+,-,*,/) as I want to use that function in a "programming language" that only supports these operations (and no if/else statements etc.). Do you have any idea what could help me here?

Comment: If you are unable to use the square root operation, then you must settle for approximate distances.

Comment: Yes, that would be fine. In fact, the taxicab geometry/Manhattan length would really fulfill my needs but it makes use of the absolute value.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to make a practical language without any if/then

Comment: What about relational operators like $>$ and $<$? I ask because you can often avoid if/then clauses with statements like `z = x * ( y < 1 ) + -1 * x ( y >= 1 )` rather than `if(y < 1 ) then z = x, else z = -x`.

Comment: I intepret @Pold 's question as without any kind of conditional statement

Comment: @qwr I'd consider a relational test as fundamentally different from a conditional statement. Conditionals would imply branching, while a relational test is just another value output from the ALU and written to memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as I understand it, you need some way to measure "distance" between two points in $\mathbb R^2$.

Let's denote two typical points by $P_1=(x_1,y_1)$ and $P_2=(x_2,y_2)$.

The simplest distance function is $d(P_1,P_2) = 0$ if $P_1=P_2$ and $d(P_1,P_2) = 1$ otherwise. This is in fact a "distance" function (in the sense of metric spaces) but it might be too crude for your purposes.

Another option is
$$
d(P_1,P_2)=(x_1-x_2)^2 + (y_1-y_2)^2 
$$

This is obviously the square of the normal Euclidean distance, but it might work for you. Depends what properties you want, of course.

Comment: I accept this answer. Of course, I was thinking about using the squared Euclidean distance before posting my question. Now, as there seem to be no other working solutions, I'll use it in my code.

Answer (score 0):

You can approximate square roots with the Babylonian method. It can calculate to any precision without branching (if / then / else)

Comment: But what about determining the starting value and when you can stop iterating?

Comment: If you really want to avoid conditional statements, you can start at any positive value. You can determine a set amount of iterations, that is not conditional.